# module.exports = function() how to call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

quick question.

I know how to export/import functions if they are placed like so

```
module.exports = {
    get: get,
    set: set
};
```

but i do not know how to run this function from another file, what exacly do i need to import/export?

```
 module.exports = function() {  
 var this = {};
 var that = {}; .... 
 much more code
 ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a two files A.js and B.js

**A.js**

```
module.exports = function() {  
   var this = {};
   var that = {}; .... 
   much more code
   ....
}
```

Now if you want to use this in B.js then A.js is using default exports and it is exporting a function so you can use it like this.

```
var a = require('./A.js');
// now as A.js is exporing a function so you can call that function by invoking a() function 
// as you have inported it into variable name a
a(); // this will call that
```

If your function needs arguments like this 
`module.exports = function(x, y) {`

then you need can pass it like

`a(1, 2);`

Comment: Thank you kind sir

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer then please upvote and accept it so it will be helpful for others seeking similar help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, what you necessarily mean when you say *"knowing how to import/export functions"* but here is what you could do to define a function and later reuse it from another file.

**test.js**

```
module.exports = () => {
   console.log('This is a sample function')
}
```

**use.js**

```
const myfunc = require('./test');
myfunc(); // Would print This is a sample function
```

I have assumed `test.js` and `use.js` to be in the same directory.

You could also have multiple functions in a file:
**test.js**

```
module.exports.fn1 = () => {
   console.log('This is sample function1')
```

}

```
module.exports.fn2 = () => {
   console.log('This is sample function2')
}
```

**use.js**

```
const myfunc1 = require('./test').fn1;
myfunc1(); 
console.log(require('./test').fn2); // Directly if you want
```

You can also read about:

- [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statement which currently is not supported by NodeJs but has a way with babel.

Comment: Thanks a lot Suhail!

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to export the function of a module (archive js):

1) "By default" -> If you have only to export one function or other data in the same archive. In that case, you can import with the alias you want:

```
export default myFunction() {...}
(In the other archive)
import alias you want(the same name or other) from `'./name_of_the_archive_to_import';
```

2) "Several functions or objects" -> If you have to export several functions or other data in the same archive. In that case, you have to call(import) those variables with the same name that were declared:

```
export variable1;
export variable2;
...
(In the other archive)
import variable1 from './name_of_the_archive_to_import';
import variable2 from './name_of_the_archive_to_import';
...
```

Comment: Also, you can import several 'exports' in one line: import { variable1, variable2, ... } from './archive_to_export.js';  or import * as imp(the name you want) from './archive_to_export.js'; In the first case, you have to call the functions by their original names, and in the second case like this way: imp.(name of the original function).